# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar Campo Autoincremento no firebird?

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, auto-incremento

Ouvi de algumas pessoas que usar Campo *auto incremento* pode dar complicações no banco de dados por conta que ele pode dar vários saltos na numeração e até se perder nas contagens. Não sei se isso é verdade, por isso queria saber quais as **vantagens** e **desvantagem** de usar campo *auto incremento* em bancos de dados `Firebird`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Firebird >= 3 um campo identidade é uma coluna associada ao gerador de sequência interno. O valor é setado automaticamente, **desde que a coluna seja omitida no INSERT**. Ou seja, muita atenção com essa parte.

Acredito que esse seja o problema que tu te referes. Caso tu não omita a coluna no insert, tu acaba assumindo o risco de errar.

Sintaxe:

```
create table t1 (
   id integer generated by default as identity primary key
)
```

Firebird 2.5 e anteriores não possuem campos auto incrementais. Tu precisas construir tu mesmo uma sequence e uma trigger.

Novamente, esse também é um problema aderente ao que tu te refere. Se tu cometer um erro na construção desses dois objetos, tu podes gerar um "salto involuntário".

Entretanto criar os objetos corretamente não é difícil:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE t1_id_sequence;
```

```
set term !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER T1_AUTOINCREMENT FOR T1
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  NEW.ID = next value for t1_id_sequence;
END!!
set term ; !!
```

Tu podes também usar uma ferramenta para criar esses objetos. DBeaver, IBExpert e Flame Robbin realizam essa tarefa de forma padronizada.

[Fonte1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553826/easiest-way-to-create-an-auto-increment-field-in-firebird-database)
[Fonte2](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity)

Comment: Tem de tomar cuidado também pois algumas situações não podem ter falhas de numeração como Apolices e Num. de Nota Fiscais a solução de Autoincremento não se aplica.